# Running setInterval on Vue method

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, setinterval

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      posts: {}
    },
    mounted: function() { 

    },
    methods: {
      updatePosts: function () {
        $.get('/api/v1/posts',function(response){
          this.posts = response.data;
          setInterval(this.updatePosts, 10000);
        }.bind(this));
      };      
    },
    created: function () {
      this.updatePosts();
    }
  });
});
```

I'm making an api call and want to run the updatepost method every 10 seconds. Currently, it runs except the 10 second timer gets reset on every page reload. How would I run this function every 10 seconds but not when the page gets refreshed?

Comment: JS will loads in every page refresh, so it will always start if you call function on `created` or `mounted`. So when you want to call this function `updatePosts` ?

Comment: When you say "page reload" do you mean a hard refresh of the page, or router-link navigation within the SPA?

Comment: I mean hard refresh of the page. So if I keep refreshing the page the function never gets run.

Comment: Check this article :  http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php

Comment: @user2486 where would I put the updatePosts function so that it runs but doesn't get reloaded in every page refresh?

Comment: "if I keep refreshing the page the function never gets run" but it looks like you call it immediately, in your `created` handler, so I'm not understanding what the problem is?   Does it need to be *exactly* ten seconds after the last update, even if there's a refresh in the interval, or something?

Comment: (or are you saying you *don't* want it to run on page reload, but only ten seconds later?  If so, that's easy, just wait ten seconds before making the first call:  `created() {setTimeout(this.updatePosts,10000)}`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, you want to stop the updatePosts call if the page refreshes, maybe you could use a route param to allow the created event to trigger updatePosts only if said param exists.

Comment: Yes, when the page refreshes the 10 second timers gets reset. So theoretically, I could refresh the page every 5 seconds and the function would never run. I want it to run the function regardless of page reload.

Comment: Ok, i get it now, well, i dont know any method that will allow you to persist the countdown through page refresh, but maybe you could use a library like moment.js and check for the time when mounted event is triggered, if current seconds its divisible by 10, then you could trigger updatePosts